# Weird behaviour of my algorithm

Tags: c, function, pointers, printf

I don't understand why the correct result is printed when I print it inside an infinite loop but doesn't print anything when I print it without a loop.

Here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>


char msg[1000];


time_t get_mtime(const char *path)
{
    struct stat statbuf;
    if (stat(path, &statbuf) == -1) {
        perror(path);
        exit(1);
    }
    return statbuf.st_mtime;
}


void encode(char* msg, char * argv[], int argc)  {

    const int bmp_header_size = 54;
    int read_code;
    int msg_idx = 0;
    int img_idx = 0;
    int bit_idx = 0;
    char c;
    FILE *img_in = NULL;
    FILE *img_out = NULL;

    if( argc < 3 ){
        printf( "Usage: %s source_bmp output_bmp message.\n", argv[0] );
        exit(1);
    }

    img_in = fopen( argv[3], "rb" );
    if( img_in == NULL ){
        printf( "Could not open the input image file.\n" );
        exit(1);
    }

    img_out = fopen( argv[2], "wb" );
    if( img_out == NULL ){
        printf( "Could not open the output file.\n" );
        exit(1);
    }



    while( ( read_code = fgetc( img_in )) != EOF ){
        c = (char)read_code;

        if( img_idx >= bmp_header_size && msg_idx <= strlen( msg ) ){
            char bit_mask = 1 << bit_idx;

            if( ( msg[msg_idx] & bit_mask) > 0 )
                c |= 1;
            else
                c &= 254;

            bit_idx++;

            if( bit_idx >= 8 ){
                bit_idx = 0;
                msg_idx++;
            }           
        }

        fputc( c, img_out );
        img_idx++;
    }


    fclose(img_in);
    fclose(img_out);

}



char* decode(char * argv[], int argc) {

   /* printf("1 = %s\n", argv[1]);
     printf("2 = %s\n", argv[2]);
     printf("3 = %s\n", argv[3]); */

    const int bmp_header_size = 54;
    const int max_msg_size = 1000;

    int i;
    int c;
    int img_idx = 0;
    int msg_idx = 0;
    int bit_idx = 0;

    FILE *img_in = NULL;

    // char msg[max_msg_size];
    img_in = fopen( argv[2], "rb" );

    if( img_in == NULL ){
        printf( "Could not open the input image file.\n" );
        exit(1);
    }

    for( i=0; i < max_msg_size; i++ )
        msg[i] = 0;

    while( ( c = fgetc( img_in )) != EOF ){
        if( img_idx >= bmp_header_size ){
            char bit_mask = 0;
            if( ( c & 1 )  > 0 )
                bit_mask |= 1 << bit_idx;

            msg[msg_idx] |= bit_mask;

            bit_idx++;

            if( bit_idx >= 8 ){
                if( msg[msg_idx] == '\0' )
                    break;
                bit_idx = 0;
                msg_idx++;
            }
        }

        img_idx++;
    }

    fclose(img_in);
    return msg;

}




int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

    char message[1000];






    while (1) {


        printf("\n Send : ");
        fgets(message, 1000, stdin);
        encode(message, argv, argc);

        long mod = get_mtime(argv[2]);
        long new = mod;

        while (1) {

            new = get_mtime(argv[2]);

            if (mod != new) {
                break;
            }
        }
        while (1) {
            printf("Received : %s ",decode(argv, argc));
        }


    }

    return 0;
}
```

Let's focus on (near the end in main())

```
        while (1) {

            strcpy(received, decodeReverse(argv, argc));
            printf("Received : %s ",received);
        }
```

With the code above i get the right output :

```
 Received : Hey
 Received : Hey
 Received : Hey
 Received : Hey
 Received : Hey
```

But if print `received` without the infinite while loop i get :

```
Received :
```

As if `received` was empty.

**EDIT :**

I cleaned up the code and applied the fixes, but it is still not working (not even with a few iteration) without an infinite loop.

Thank you guys !

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {` is not a valid prototype for `main`, use `int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {`

Comment: First of all fix the error pointed out by @mksteve and @Magisch, for example by passing the `received` buffer to `decodeReverse()` from outside, preferably as a call parameter. But that does not explain why decoding fail on single call but it works when iterated. Are there any side effects we haven't catch yet? Try running exactly two or three iterations instead of infinite loop and see results.

Comment: @CiaPan I tried with two and three iterations,  nothing is printed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char msg[max_msg_size];
```

Is a local variable within the function `decode`, yet you try to return it.

The fact that it works with an infinite loop has to do with how the compiler happens to interpret the loop, it is however, undefined behaviour.

To fix, declare `msg` outside of the `decode` function.

Keep in mind, that you, of course, also need to do this to the 
lines `char* output = msg` delcare that outside the function first before you set msg to it and return it.

Comment: That's basically a recap of mksteve's answer, including the typical words "yet" and "happens to".

Comment: I usually dont read the other answers while writing my own, and I often start writing my own and then do something, then continue to write my own.

Comment: Better than my answer - as it also suggests how to fix it :-)

Comment: @Magisch Thank you so much for your answer, but unfortunatly it is still not working. I declared msg `char msg[1000]` as a global variable and still no print...

Comment: You also did the same treatment to `    char *output = msg;
    return output;` right?

Comment: @Magisch Actually I changed that line to `return msg;` It should work ?

Comment: Not sure you can return a char array when the function type states you want to return a string literal.

Comment: @EricSchaal: Making `msg` static or global should fix your mistake. You open the original image, `argv[1]`, for decoding. Open `argv[2]` instead.

Comment: @MOehm Assuming this works for him, do you want me to delete my answer and write your own summing this up or should I edit it in?

Comment: Hmm, well I guess you can't as it doesn't work. I declared as global `char *output[1000];` and then changed `return msg` to `    *output = msg; return *output;` It is still not working. I'm really sorry about that, I just started learning C. I've spent days on that code.

Comment: @EricSchaal try out MOehm 's suggestion.

Comment: @Magisch: No, keep your answer, especially as it has already been upvoted. Even if I suspected you of parrotting mksteve's answer, the basic observation, namely that OP returned the address of a local variable is correct. And your proposed solution is good, too, although I'd solve it differently. Mistyping `argv[1]` for `argv[2]` is only the explanation why it doesn't work even after applying your fix.

Comment: @MOehm decoding image `argv[1]` is not a mistake. Indeed a message will be encoded into this image by another instance (another "use"r )of this program. So When image `argv[1]` is modified, decode will decode the message inside image `argv[1]`. It's a stenographic chat. But thanks for your answer ! :)

Comment: @EricSchaal: I've copied your code and have thrown out the unused `decode`, `decodeReversePrint` and `fetch` functions as well as the `mtime` loop and the long comment stretches. In `encode`, you read from `argv[1]` and write to `argv[2]`. So in `decode`, you should read from the encoded image, `argv[2]`., no? I've gotten good results from that. (In general, I think that your program could benefit from a cleaner structure. Argument checking should be done in `main`, for example.)

Comment: @MOehm Well if you want to read your own message you must decode `argv[1]` but I want to decode the message in 'argv[2]' that will be written by a second instance of the program. (with arguments swapped when calling the binary)

Comment: @EricSchaal: Okay, good point, but how am I supposed to know this? `argv[1]` was just any old bitmap file I found. Anyway, decoding a properly encoded file worked with the fix suggested here.

Answer (score 2):

The buffer being returned is being overwritten.

```
char msg[max_msg_size];
```

only lives within the function, yet is being returned.

The compiler jigs around memory for the loop, meaning it happens to survive, but maybe not on different compiler / platform